# How do I make pretty URLs with Tornado for static HTML?

Tags: tornado, friendly-url

I have a directory `static` and I have set `static_url_prefix` to `/static/`, so my HTML file can be accessed at `server/static/panel.html`. Now, I would like to redirect `server/panel` to this URL.

I've tried a number of variations on `(r"/(panel\.html)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,  {'path': ''})` in application, but none of them work :-(. How can I get this working?

Comment: Could you please post your application initialisation code. I'd expect to see static_path being set, as in the following example http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#static-files-and-aggressive-file-caching but you haven't mentioned it.

Comment: @RodHyde: I have the following in my code: `'static_path': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following route using [RedirectHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/_modules/tornado/web.html#RedirectHandler):

```
(r"panel", tornado.web.RedirectHandler, {'url': '/static/panel.html'})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but I'd like it if the URL didn't change but was instead displayed as `mysite.com/panel`